# How to get access to input.value in Formik form during onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm currently making a form in React JS, using Formik library. I faced a problem with validation, I need to change invalid letters with an empty string.

```
str.replace(/\D/, ');
```

But I can't get access to the `input` value in Formik. I need to validate values on every key click but there's no info in Formik docs about it.

Component `Form`:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Formik, Form, useFormikContext } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import FormInput from '../Inputs/FormInput';


const EditUserSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  surname: Yup.string()
      .required('Поле обязательно'),
  userName: Yup.string()
      .required('Поле обязательно'),
  patronymic: Yup.string()
      .required('Поле обязательно'),
  phone: Yup.string()
      .required('Поле обязательно'),
  email: Yup.string()
      .required('Поле обязательно')
});




<Formik
    initialValues = {{
        surname,
        userName,
        patronymic,
        phone,
        email
    }}
    validationSchema={EditUserSchema}

    onSubmit = {values => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))
    }}
>
    {formik => (
        <Form id="edit-user-form"> 
            <FormInput
                label="Фамилия"
                name="surname"
                type="text" 
                formik={formik}/>

            <FormInput
                label="Имя"
                name='userName'
                type='text'/>

            <FormInput
                label="Отчество"
                name="patronymic"
                type="text" />

            <FormInput
                label="Телефон"
                name="phone"
                type="phone" />

            <FormInput
                label="Почта"
                name="email"
                type="email" 
                validate={validateEmail}/>
        </Form>
    )}
</Formik>
```

Component needed to be validated:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { ErrorMessage, useField } from 'formik';
import './formInput.scss';

const FormInput = ({label='', formik, placeholder=null, classNames='', ...props}) => {

    const [field, meta] = useField(props);
    
    return (
        <div className="form__input-wrapper">
            <label htmlFor={field.name}>{label}</label>
            <input
                className={`${classNames}`}
                {...field} {...props}
            />
            {meta.touched && meta.error ? (<div>{meta.error}</div>) : null}
            {/* <ErrorMessage component="div" name={meta.error}/> */}
        </div>
    )
    
}


export default FormInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add a submit button in your form and then you need to add the formik handleSubmit on your form like this

```
<Form id="edit-user-form" onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
```

Now you should get all the input values in onSubmit function of formik from where you can use string.replace() function to replace the final input values and then submit your form with these values.

Yup can only check for validation errors but not update those values